# vscode regex find/replace replace characters inside string

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-code

I want to replace all instances of

```
() => import('@/components/something/Something')
```

with

```
() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "components--something--Something" */ '@/components/something/Something')
```

So far I have this find/replace regex

Find: `\(\) => import\('(.+?)'\)`

Replace: `() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "$1" */ '$1')`

Which replaces:

```
() => import('@/components/something/Something')
```

with

```
() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "@/components/something/Something" */ '@/components/something/Something')
```

My problem is that I don't know how to replace the "@" and "/" characters

Do I need to execute two find/replace queries or can it be done with a single one? I want to remove the "@" entirely and replace the "/" by "--"

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It can't be done in only one find/replace.

Comment: good to know.. but I would still like to know how to do it as two find/replace operations

Comment: Sorry but tonight I'm watching Twin Peaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With two find/replace:

```
find: (\(\) => import\()'@/([^']*)'\)
replace: $1/* webpackChunkName: "$2" */  '@/$2')
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/H4rjAe/2)

and

```
find: ((?:\G(?!^)|\(\) => import\(/\*)[^/*]*)/
replace: $1--
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sPg4M6/1)

Answer (score 0):

If the path *always* matches the `@/part1/part2/part3` pattern, then you could group those parts individually and use your backreferences like so:

Find:

```regex
\(\) => import\('(@/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?))'\)
```

Replace:

```regex
() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "$2--$3--$4" */ '$1')
```

However, if the number of path parts varies (which is more likely) then you're best bet is probably a second and third set of find and replaces along these lines:

**Get rid of the `@/`**

Find:

```regex
(?<=\(\) => import\(/\* webpackChunkName: ")@/
```

Replace:

(Replace with nothing)

**Convert `/` to `--`**

Find:

```regex
(?<=\(\) => import\(/\* webpackChunkName: ")(.*?)/(.*?)(?=" \*/)
```

Replace:

```regex
$1--$2
```

(You'll have to run this several times per line)