# Find & Replace Markdown Image in VSCode using Regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have lots of markdown files with 100+ images referenced inside it.

I'm looking for a way to find & replace them.

It should remove the caption of the image & the last part of image should be appended with `{width=100%}`

```
![a caption](./img.png)
```

should be replaced with

```
![](./img.png){width=100%}
```

How do I do it in VSCode?

I have found the regex for image is `!\[[^\]]*\]\((.*?)\s*("(?:.*[^"])")?\s*\)` but don't know how to move forward?

The only thing I could figure out was appending `{width=100%}` in the `replace` input.

Currently, my `find` input looks like:

```
!\[[^\]]*\]\((.*?)\s*("(?:.*[^"])")?\s*\)
```

And `replace` input looks like:

```
!\[[^\]]*\]\((.*?)\s*("(?:.*[^"])")?\s*\){width=100%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer while [reading an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57666665/6141587) in another tab.

```
find: !\[[^\]]*\]\((.*?)\s*("(?:.*[^"])")?\s*\)
replace: ![]($1){width=100%}
```