# replace markdown images without alt with filename using regex using find & replace in vscode?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

i have multiple markdown files that contain images without alt that look like:

```markdown
# my file

![](./filename-1.png)

# this is an example image

![](./this-is-a-an-example-image.png)
```

i want to replace them with alt from the filename but without the `.png` extension & without `./` & replacing hyphens (`-` ) with empty spaces.

so the above markdown would look like:

```markdown
# my file

![filename 1](./filename-1.png)

# this is an example image

![this is an example image](./this-is-an-example-image.png)
```

i can't do this manually as i have 100+ images so would love to automate this with a regex using vscode's find & replace.

i had [previously removed alt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74149194/find-replace-markdown-image-in-vscode-using-regex) but want it back now. i didn't version control it so can't go back either.

how do i do it?

Comment: write a simple Python/JavaScript/... script and search the images and perform the replace with a callback function in the regex-find-replace call, you want too much in 1 go for regex, in particular you want to search-replace inside the matched string (- to space)

Comment: @rioV8 is this not possible with regex? i don't want too much. i only want to read the contents between parentheses `(...)` & use that to replace it in `[...]` so it's like 1 piece of info. of course, i can do it in scripting language but i thought it'd be easy like my previous question which is kinda similar.

Comment: you also want to replace stuff with spaces, that will not work in 1 go, you can do it in multiple steps as long as there are `-` in the alt, you haven't brushed up on regex since your previous question, it is very similar what you want to do now

Comment: @rioV8 i am a noob at regex but i always try 50 times before asking. and because it's very similar, i thought i'd ask. even if it's 2 steps, it's still better than 1. i just can't get the filename in the square bracket, rest i think i can do.

Comment: @rioV8 i even got the first part to [work on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6nzrZW/1) but i can't find the `a-filename` part on vscode

Comment: the trick is: find an ALT text with a `-` character, place capture groups before and after the `-` and replace it with `$1 $2`, do this as long as there is search hit (there is still a minus in an ALT)

Comment: @rioV8 that makes sense. unfortunately, i couldn't find a kebab-case regex that finds capture groups without the `-`. i'll brush up my regex skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it with an extension, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), that can run two find and replaces in a row.  Install the extension and then make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": [
      "(!\\[\\])\\((\\.\\/)?(.*)(\\.(png|jpg|gif)\\))",
      "(?<=!\\[.*)(-)(?=.*\\])"
    ],
    "replace": ["![$3]($2$3$4", " "],
    "isRegex": true,
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  }
}
```

I made it to handle other image formats which you may not need.

The first find and replace just moves the filename (minus the leading `.\` and trailing `.png`) into the `![]`.

The second find matches just the `-` in that `![asdasd-asdasd-asdasd]` and replaces those `-` with `" "` i.e., one space.

[image: add markdown image alt text]

Comment: that works fantastically. putting keybindings in `.vscode/keybindings.json` didn't work but [globally in the extensions place worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791170/6141587). just curious, is there a way to do it like i did below in other answer? like replace `a-filename-in-the-image` inside brackets `[]` with `spaces` like `[a filename in the image`? or not possible?

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Do you mean in one step from nothing in the `[]`?  Or just as a second step, which is what this keybinding does in its second regex: `(?<=!\\[.*)(-)(?=.*\\])`?

Comment: no, i meant about my answer below. i got first step working like getting the filename from `()` & putting it inside `[]` without `./` & `.png` but my 2nd step of separating kebab-case `[a-filename-of-an-image]` to empty space `[a filename of an image]` isn't working. that's what i'm asking just out of curiousity. your solution works fantastically though. previously i used to manually write `alt`... now i just press `⌥m` & it magically fills in the alt :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the demo on `regex101` to find the group between `./` & `.png` → https://regex101.com/r/gMgc6r/1

**important**: i enabled the search in each file, not the sidebar & ticked the `.*` button that says `use regular expression`

then i typed the following:

```bash
find: !\[\]\(.\/(.*).png\)
replace: ![$1](./$1.png)
```

this converts:

```
![](./a-filename.png)
```

to

```
![a-filename](./a-filename.png)
```

this finds the string between each bracket `[` & `]` → https://regex101.com/r/Ke89CK/1 but i couldn't figure out how to use it in vscode.

i have to convert `[a-filename]` by replacing `-` with empty spaces.

```bash
find: ?
replace: ?
```